# ScrollView page slide by button pressed smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I have tried to scroll page images by pressing button on `scrollView` object by using `SMF.UI.ScrollView.scrollX="100%"`  horizontally but I did not get any response.

Is there any way to scroll pages rather than swipe by hand?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : 
SMF.UI.ScrollView.scrollX = 100;